# Multiple names for the same type and matching in Ocaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, type-inference

I am trying to match different combinations of faces (in terms of bigraph theory) using this library http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~michele/docs/_doc/bigraph/index.html

One of the functions to do so is supposed to be as follows:

```
let type_of_edge (edge:Link.edg) = 
 let {Link.i; _;} = edge
 in
  match i with
  | Link.Face.empty -> "777"
  | _ -> "888"
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

> This pattern matches values of type 'a list
>          but a pattern was expected which matches values of type t

I know that in the module Link.Face every object is of type called "t" but why if I use one of the functions (Link.Face.empty) from that module compiler treats it as of a' list type ?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the answer for my question is:

```
let type_of_edge (edge:Link.edg) = 
 let {Link.i; _;} = edge
 in
  match i with
  | tmp when tmp = Link.Face.empty -> "777"
  | _ -> "888"
```

I found 
[OCaml Pattern match with non-constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435572/ocaml-pattern-match-with-non-constants)
very helpful in solving this issue.